# ImportError: cannot import name ‘is_compiling’ from ‘torch._dynamo’

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision, nvidia-jetson, detectron

This is a repeat of the question from [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/importerror-cannot-import-name-is-compiling-from-torch-dynamo/255867?u=shyamashi)

I have a jetson agx orin developer kit and I am following instructions from [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pytorch-for-jetson/72048) to install cuda version of pytorch and torchvision. I successfully installed everything and the verification outputs are the following

```
>>> import torch
>>> import torchvision
>>> print(torch.__version__)
1.14.0a0+44dac51c.nv23.02
>>> print('CUDA available: ' + str(torch.cuda.is_available()))
CUDA available: True
>>> print('cuDNN version: ' + str(torch.backends.cudnn.version()))
cuDNN version: 8600
>>> print(torchvision.__version__)
0.14.1
```

Then I ran the following inference script

```
from detectron2.engine import DefaultPredictor
from detectron2.utils.visualizer import Visualizer
import cv2
from detectron2.utils.visualizer import ColorMode
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2 import model_zoo
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file("Cityscapes/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN.yaml"))


cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = os.path.join("/detectron2_on_kitti/mask_rcnn_output/output_resnet-50/", "model_final.pth") 
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.7   # set a custom testing threshold
predictor = DefaultPredictor(cfg)

imgPath = "/dataset/data_semantics/testing/image_2/000000_10.png"
im = cv2.imread(imgPath)
outputs = predictor(im)  
v = Visualizer(im[:, :, ::-1],
               metadata={},
               scale=0.5,
               instance_mode=ColorMode.SEGMENTATION   # remove the colors of unsegmented pixels. This option is only available for segmentation models
)
out = v.draw_instance_predictions(outputs["instances"].to("cpu"))
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 20))
plt.imshow(out.get_image()[:, :, ::-1])
plt.show()
```

It produces the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'is_compiling' from 'torch._dynamo'` . Any thoughts on this?